# Compiling multiple python scripts into one file

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python and used to C, and I'm trying to find a way to possibly compile several .py files in a directory together as one file. Some of the methods I've seen were to make an egg or bundle them up as a zip file and run it with 'python foo.zip,' but I'm pretty restricted on those options.
The .zip method is closest to what I'm after but what I need is more along the lines of importing that file in the main script and not as an argument to the interpreter.

I have to run this code on several machines and would rather not have to copy a whole folder of modules with it, and would also rather not have to paste all of my code into one file.
Caveats: I'm running a pretty old version of python (2.4.3) on machines that are cut off from the Internet and that I don't have physical access to, so I can't install other modules. I would have to be able to pull it off with old vanilla python.

Comment: Deploying the directory is probably the way to go as Python's execution is different from C (where you can fold everything up into one file). The alternative is to develop your application for this purpose and to develop everything in one file from the start. Other than a few commands before / after deployment, what are the downsides of using the directory approach in this case?

Comment: I'm distributing this code to several machines and I wanted to keep the clutter to a minimum (i.e. having the script, its config file, and the module). Putting all of the code in one file makes it a little more messy than I would like.
It was mostly for asthetic purposes but I guess I can't get around either having only one file or distributing it as a folder.

Comment: I presume you can SSH into the machines? You can consider using a tool such as Ansible for deploying. Conceptually I think it's best to keep the code as multiple files. The steps of creating the directories and copying multiple files isn't that much more and it matches Python's "natural" usage.

Comment: I may just have to keep it separate, thanks. I'm not entirely used to the pythonic way of doing things yet.